# Simplify a switch statement

Tags: dart

I would like to sum up the code below to make it less and more beautiful.

I have 5 models (`User`, `Group`, `Event`, `Member`, `Appearance`), three shown below.

I’d like to simplify the code.

```
  String getId(uri) {
    String pathSegment;
    if (uri.pathSegments.length >= 2) {
      pathSegment = uri.pathSegments[1];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
    switch (resource) {
      case 'users':
        for (User user in models[resource]) {
          if (user.id == pathSegment) {
            return pathSegment;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        }
        break;
      case 'groups':
        for (Group group in models[resource]) {
          if (group.id == pathSegment) {
            return pathSegment;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        }
        break;
      case 'events':
        for (Event event in models[resource]) {
          if (event.id == pathSegment) {
            return pathSegment;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        }
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: You can replace your whole switch-case block by just this: ```return ((models[resource].firstWhere((it) => it.id == pathSegment, orElse: () => null)) != null) ? pathSegment : null;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `User`, `Group`, and `Event` have a common `id`, then You can simplify your code by using `dynamic` type. See [related documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system).

```
String getId(uri) {
  String pathSegment;
  if (uri.pathSegments.length >= 2) {
     pathSegment = uri.pathSegments[1];
  } else {
    return null;
  }

  return _getIdFromItems(models[resource], pathSegment);
}

String _getIdFromItems(List<dynamic> items, String pathSegment) {
   for (dynamic item in items) {
     if (item.id == pathSegment) {
       return pathSegment;
     } else {
       return null;
     }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Note that this assumes that there aren't other values for `resource` where `item.id == pathSegment` could be satisfied.  In the original code, a value of `resource` other than `'users'`, `'groups'`, and `'events`' would return `null`.